# number to be printed in a format using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using java script to print a 10 digit number. example 1234567891. But i want that number to be printed in a particular format link 123.456.789-1. Can somebody please help me to sort this.

Comment: First, don't mix javaScript & Java - they're different things. Second, please elaborate your format a bit more

Comment: Hey Vivek, in your link 123.456.789-1 the last symbol is -(dash) or .(dot)

Comment: please put your code to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, my sincere apologizes. I m very new to java and learning on daily basis. Here i couldn't attach the entire code, so i splitted into parts.

Comment: int randNum2 = new Double( (Math.random()+1) * 100000000).intValue();
  String aString = Integer.toString(randNum2);
  int[] cpf = new int[aString.length()+3];

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++) {
   cpf[i] = Character.digit(aString.charAt(i), 10);
  }
  cpf[9]=10*cpf[0]+9*cpf[1]+8*cpf[2]+7*cpf[3]+6*cpf[4]+5*cpf[5]+4*cpf[6]+3*cpf[7]+2*cpf[8];
  cpf[9]=11-(cpf[9] %11);
  if(cpf[9]>9)
  {
   cpf[9]=0;
  }

Comment: cpf[10]=11*cpf[0]+10*cpf[1]+9*cpf[2]+8*cpf[3]+7*cpf[4]+6*cpf[5]+5*cpf[6]+4*cpf[7]+3*cpf[8]+2*cpf[9];
  cpf[10]=11-(cpf[10] %11);
  if(cpf[10]>9)
  {
   cpf[10]=0;
  } 
  String sValue="";
 
  for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
  {  sValue+=cpf[i];  }
  System.out.println("a"+sValue+"a");
 }

}

Comment: The last output gives a random number with alphabets like "a16826863880a". But i want this to be displayed as "a168.268.638-80a".

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to do it:

```
var num = "1234567891";
var formattedNum = formatNum(num);
console.log(formattedNum); //returns 123.456.789-1

function formatNum(num) {
    var arr = num.split('');
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        output += arr[i];
        if (i === 2 || i === 5) output += '.';
        if (i === 8) output += '-';
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I m getting error for 'console' and 'var'.  'var' cannot resolved to a type and console cannot be resolved. function gives this error - "insert ". new" to complete ClassInstanceCreationExpressionName.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert to a string with leading zeroes,
then insert the punctuation as you desire.

```
function formatnum(n) {
 n = ("0000000000" + n).substr(-10); // take the last 10 digits of the padded string
 return ( n.substr(0,3) + "." + n.substr(3,3) + "." + n.substr(6,3) + "-" + n.substr(9,1) );
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error for the 'substr', though i converted to string

Comment: I tried it in both Firefox and Chrome, and did not get any errors.
What error are you seeing?